# How to unit test an ASP.NET MVC action that uses ServiceStack's JsonServiceClient()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, servicestack

I have a fairly deep understanding of testable design when working with ASP.NET MVC and have been successful in applying that understanding to building testable services with ServiceStack. However, one very important piece of the puzzle eludes me, how do I unit test MVC actions that take a dependency on JsonServiceClient? I understand I can wrap JsonServiceClient in my own abstraction but is there a ServiceStack-based solution?

For example, give a contrived service that uses DTOs fetch a list of planets:

```
public class PlanetsService : Service
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; } // injected via Funq

    public object Get(PlanetsRequest request)
    {
        var planets = Repository.GetPlanets();

        return new PlanetsResponse{ Planets = planets };
    }
}
```

Let's say I have a simple MVC action that uses JsonServiceClient to fetch data, does some work, and then returns a view with a view model that includes my planets list:

```
public class PlanetsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient; // injected with JsonServiceClient in AppHost

    public PlanetsController(IRestClient restClient)
    {
        _restClient = restClient;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var request = new PlanetsRequest();
        var response = _restClient.Get(request);

        // maybe do some work here that we want to test

        return View(response.Planets);
    }
}
```

I started down the path of using the DirectServiceClient as my IRestClient in my unit tests however DirectServiceClient.Get(IRequest request) is not implemented (throwing a NotImplementedException). My tests are using NUnit and inherit from ServiceStack's TestBase:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PlanetsControllerTests : TestBase
{
    [Test]
    public void Index_Get_ReturnsViewResult()
    {
        var restClient = new DirectServiceClient(this, new ServiceManager(typeof(PlanetsService).Assembly));
        var controller = new PlanetsController(restClient);
        var viewResult =  controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    }

    protected override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So I guess the real questions are: Can DirectServiceClient actually be supplied for IRestClient for unit testing? Does ServiceStack offer a strategy for what I assume is a common scenario for developers using ServiceStack with ASP.NET MVC? Am I working outside the scope of ServiceStack's offerings and perhaps I should just code to my own abstractions that hide JsonServiceClient?

I have spent a lot of time looking for recommendations online and while there are plenty of end-to-end integration testing examples none seem specific to what I am trying to do with unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just create your own mock implementation of `IRestClient`? Or better use something like RhinoMock to mock the interface and set expectations and responses?

For example, using RhinoMock (not sure about the real syntax but it should be clear what is happening):

```
[Test]
public void Index_Get_ReturnsViewResult()
{
    var restClient = MockRepository.GetMock<IRestClient>();
    var controller = new PlanetsController(restClient);
    restClient.Expect(c => c.Get(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(new PlanetsResponse{ /* some fake Planets */ });
    var viewResult =  controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    // here you can also assert that the Model has the list of Planets you injected...
}
```

Comment: I was hoping ServiceStack offered a mock/fake implementation of IRestClient, specifically DirectServiceClient. I agree with your suggestion in that I can create my own mock implementation, use test doubles with IoC, or use a mocking framework like RhinoMock. I was hoping ServiceStack had an out-of-box solution for what I need to do specifically - as test-friendly as it is it seems to fall short when it comes to building testable clients. I suppose I just need to do a little leg work myself and build what I need, certainly not the end of the world. Thanks for the suggestions though.